# Nivo Slider - Responsive/Centered Caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

I've downloaded and implemented the Nivo Slider on my website. Since implementing it, I've found a few bugs, but I'm looking for help with getting my caption centered on the screen.

Margin:auto usually works for this to ensure a div is always centered (I think..) - but I can't get it to work with my site..

***My HTML:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Max Klimmek - Portfolio, Clothing, Travel</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />
      <script src="script/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="script/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(window).load(function() {
          $('#slider').nivoSlider()          
          });
        </script>

  </head>
  <body>

      <header id="site-header">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Clothing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Resume</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
              <img src="img/cover.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption1"/>
              <img src="img/cover1.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption1"/>
              <img src="img/cover.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption1"/>
              <img src="img/cover1.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption1"/>
          </div>

          <div id="htmlcaption1" style="display:none">
          <div class="nivo-caption1" >Simple. <br> Clean.</div>
       </div>

      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**My CSS for the caption:**

```
    .nivo-caption1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top: 5%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:none;
    font-family: 'Gotham';
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:50px;
    line-height:44px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase; /* converts text to UPPERCASE */
}
```

If I remove the Margin-Top the caption doesn't even appear.. I've added margin:auto to all the other divs that contain this caption/slider.

Anyone got any ideas of how I could ensure the nivo-caption is always centered even when I resize the browser window?

Attached is a photo of how it looks now..

Any help would be great!

Thanks,
Max[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xu9H.jpg)

Comment: Currently your class is called "nivo-caption1" but you're trying to style "nivo-caption".  Was that just a typo? If not, you should start by assigning the correct class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem. I'm not sure if it's the correct way things should be coded, but it works.. If anyone can see how my code might cause issues in the future, please let me know.

I added some bits of code to the css and it solved everything.

**My HTML is exactly the same as above:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Max Klimmek - Portfolio, Clothing, Travel</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />
      <script src="script/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="script/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(window).load(function() {
          $('#slider').nivoSlider()          
          });
        </script>

  </head>
  <body>

      <header id="site-header">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Clothing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Resume</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
              <img src="img/cover.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption1"/>
              <img src="img/cover1.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption1"/>
              <img src="img/cover.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption1"/>
              <img src="img/cover1.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption1"/>
          </div>

          <div id="htmlcaption1" style="display:none">
          <div class="nivo-caption1" >Simple. <br> Clean.</div>
       </div>

      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**The New CSS for the NivoCaption container:**

```
/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:45px;
    line-height:44px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase; /* converts text to UPPERCASE */
}

.nivo-caption1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

**The pieces I added to ensure center alignment were:**

```
justify-content: center;
margin-left: -85px;
margin-top: -200px;
width: 100%;
```

Now I just have to figure out solutions to the other bugs with this slider:

1. pauseTime not being applied to all slides.
2. Delay on caption load.

Cheers for your helps guys!

Max

Answer (score 1):

The reason margin:auto isn't working for this particular case is two-fold.

1. You need to have a width set.
2. The caption is being positioned absolutely and this will override it. Even if you do set a width, it won't matter in this case.

It's ok to position it absolutely for the slider. I don't think it would work out too well if you didn't. All that needs to be done here is to set the left attribute on the caption so that it pushes the caption over to the center of the screen.

In order to do this you would need to calculate the difference between the width of the slider and the width of the caption and divide the result in half. This will give you the correct amount. It looks like the slider spans the full width of the page, so we would need to calculate this difference dynamically because when the window size changes, so does the width of the slider. We'll need a little help from javascript to accomplish this.

Something like this might help:

`function centerCaption(){
    var caption = $('.nivo-caption');
    caption.css('left', ($('#slider').width() - caption.width()) / 2);
}`

Here is a slimmed down working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/ma645ao8/2/

Comment: I've implemented what you posted in fiddle, and this too does not solve the problem. The thing is, the width of the slider actually does change width when the window is resized. 

My problem is that the caption is not centered over the slider, even when the screen is resized. Your solution so far has not solved my problem, but I can see in theory how you think it should. However  now the caption is positioned permanently to the left of the screen, I think there is some other css at work here overriding mine..

Comment: It's possible there are other styles being applied from somewhere else, but would be hard to tell without inspecting the site itself. The code I posted in jsfiddle was just a sample and would need to be altered slightly in order to work. For example, the class names differed. Glad you found a solution though, good luck with the rest!

Answer (score 0):

When you fix your class name, I *believe* that if you set a width to your div and then use margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto, the element should center.

```
.nivo-caption { 
width:300px; 
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

This assumes you don't have other elements that force that element to not be able to move.

Comment: I don't think the class name makes a difference, any edits made to nivo-caption will be applied correctly to the nivo-caption1 class..

After applying your suggested fix, it acts just like before when I had changed the margin-left/right to auto.. What happens is, the div now moves below the slider. The div is centered, but it does not overlay on the slider div..

Any other ideas?